# React Formik FastField doesn't set initial value with type="checkbox" and type="radio" with material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik

**Current Behavior**

Hi, I'm trying to use FastField with material-ui to avoid unnecessary re-render. A checkbox's and a radio button's initial value are being set, but neither the checkbox nor the radio button display the correct initial status. The following code sandbox link shows that Field works but FastField doesn't. Is there something I miss?

**Expected behavior**

The checkbox and radio button are supposed to display correctly with corresponding initial value.

**Reproducible example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-currying-83dbw?file=/src/App.js

**Software  Version(s)**

React   16.12

Formik  2.1.5

Material-ui 4.11.0

Browser Chrome 84.0.4147.125

Thanks